# Unicode normalization forms Explanation (Java)

Tags: java, string

I'm using `Normalizer.normalize(url, Normalizer.Form.NFD)` to avoid having characters like `é` in my url, and I do not understand the meaning of the `Normalizer.Form` consts (NFC, NFD, NFKC, and NFKD) or when to use each one.

I consulted the documentation but this did not help at all.
[image]

Does anyone have any idea on this topic?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://towardsdatascience.com/difference-between-nfd-nfc-nfkd-and-nfkc-explained-with-python-code-e2631f96ae6c and the links it has to Wiki and UAX#15: _"TL;DR: use NFKC method"_.

Comment: It’s literally the first hyperlink on [the documentation for Normalizer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/Normalizer.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **D**=Decomposed `e` `´`
- **C**=Composed `é`

The K is for ligatures, one letter `ﬃ`(ffi) or 3: f f i.

This is mentioned in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html):

> Characters with accents or other adornments can be encoded in several
> different ways in Unicode. For example, take the character A-acute. In
> Unicode, this can be encoded as a single character (the "composed"
> form):
>
> ```
>   U+00C1    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH ACUTE or as two separate characters (the "decomposed" form):
>   U+0041    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
>   U+0301    COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT To a user of your program, however, both of these sequences should be treated as the same
> ```
>
> "user-level" character "A with acute accent". When you are searching
> or comparing text, you must ensure that these two sequences are
> treated as equivalent. In addition, you must handle characters with
> more than one accent. Sometimes the order of a character's combining
> accents is significant, while in other cases accent sequences in
> different orders are really equivalent. Similarly, the string "ffi"
> can be encoded as three separate letters:
>
> ```
>   U+0066    LATIN SMALL LETTER F
>   U+0066    LATIN SMALL LETTER F
>   U+0069    LATIN SMALL LETTER I or as the single character
>   U+FB03    LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FFI
> ```

So in your case you want NFKD, full decomposition.

```
s = Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("\\p{M}", "");
```

The latter `replaceAll`just removes the *combining diacritical marks*, the zero-width accents `´`. There are still problematic latin letters like

- `ŀ` Polish small L with strike-through
- `ı` Turkish small I without dot
- `İ` Turkish capital I with dot

But might already been doing a non-ASCII replace.

Of course nowadays one might have [Unicode URLs](https://eurid.eu/en/register-a-eu-domain/domain-names-with-special-characters-idns/) to some degree, sites with special characters.
And with some care those characters would not get mangled.

An other use of normalisation in decomposed form is for sorting country names alphabetically: `Österreich` (Austria in German) before `P`.

---

***Some Details***

The K stands for "compatibility" and hence is important.

One can have more than one accent (zero-width *combining diacritical mark*) at a letter.

One can have a String with both composed and decomposed letters.

So actually NFC does: Canonical decomposition, followed by canonical composition. So in order to do a good composition it is best to first decompose which does the Normalizer for you.

Composition also has its use; for instance it is guaranteed canonical (single norming form), and is compact for `String.codePointAt`.

Comment: @BasilBourque accents as separate Unicode code points (symbols), or several accented letters as separate Unicode code points; those are features of Unicode itself. Hopefully the added "Some Details" clarifies that somewhat.